# File is not being deleted even though file.delete() is returning true

Tags: java, android, android-file

I have an activity which allows the user to snap a picture and `onActivityResult()` will create a temp file in the cache dir to store it before i upload it to the server.

This is how I start the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
```

Here is the code inside **onActivityResult**:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA) {
            try {
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                File photoFile = new File(getActivity().getCacheDir(), "userprofilepic_temp.jpg");

                boolean b = false;
                if(photoFile.isFile()){
                    b = photoFile.delete();
                }
                b = photoFile.createNewFile(); //saves the file in the cache dir, TODO delete this file after account creation
                userPhotoFilePath = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();

                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(photoFile);
                fos.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fos.close();

                displayUserPhoto(photoFile);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
        else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO_LIBRARY) {

        }

    }
}
```

And displayUserPhoto is just a simple Glide call:

```
@Override
public void displayUserPhoto(File photoFile) {
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(photoFile)
            .into(userPhotoView);
}
```

Since I want to override the previous picture if a user decides to retake the picture, I check if the photoFile is a file. If it is, I delete it. Then create a new file.

The problem is that it always return the same initial picture. The file is never deleted even though I call `.delete()`.

Since I am using the app's cache dir, I don't need write permissions, but just incase I tried including that but it still didn't work.

Edit: added full flow below

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this in a debugger, breaking after the `delete()`, and observing whether the file is actually deleted before you create and write a new one? If it is, then the behavior you're seeing could be caused instead by re-writing the same data to the new file.

Comment: "The file is never deleted even though I call .delete()." -- even if the file were not deleted, you are overwriting its contents. Hence, your problem lies elsewhere, perhaps in your `displayUserPhoto()` implementation. Also, please get rid of the `ByteArrayOutputStream`, as that is a terrible waste of memory, since you are just turning around and writing the data using a `FileOutputStream`. Pass the `FileOutputStream` to `compress()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I added the full flow. I don't see where it could be messing up. The flow seems pretty basic.

Comment: I would guess that Glide is not detecting the fact that the image file changed contents and is working purely off of an in-memory cache.

Comment: @AndyThomas I did and since delete() is return true, it was deleted. Also createNewFile also returns true (if it didn't create a new file, it would return false).

Comment: @CommonsWare it set the same picture even after i completely close the app

Comment: If by "completely close the app", you simply mean pressing the BACK button to exit the activity, your process is still around, and Glide probably has a process-level in-memory cache. Have you looked at the file yourself, using your development machine instead of your app?

Comment: @CommonsWare, no i mean like killing it from the multitasking menu. I haven't, but since delete() is returning true and createNewFile() is returning true, I figured it had to actually be deleted

Comment: @CommonsWare I figured it out, you were right about Glide. It was caching  in the disk

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what to do here since the answer is completely different than what I initially thought it was, so it doesn't really pertain to the question.

Glide was not only saving a cache in memory but also on disk, hence why i kept getting the same image.

The solution is simply this:

```
Glide.with(this)
            .load(photoFile)
            .skipMemoryCache(true)//this
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)//and this
            .into(userPhotoView);
```